# ft_stopword_file does not work with compressed tables

Tags: mysql, myisam, stop-words, my.cnf

I added `ft_stopword_file = ""` to `my.cnf` in order to ignore stopwords.
Next, I compressed the MyISAM table using myisampack and myisamchk.
But there was a problem with stopwords, they are no longer ignored. That is, mysql query returns empty results for stopwords.
Why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: *NOTE: FULLTEXT indexes on MyISAM tables must be rebuilt after changing this variable (ft_stopword_file) or the contents of the stopword file.*

Comment: I have already used REPAIR TABLE but the result is the same.

Comment: Rebuild the index explicitly nevertheless.

Comment: Do you mean OPTIMIZE TABLE ?
My problem occurs right after command: myisamchk -rq --sort-index --analyze table

Comment: I mean drop and re-create FTI.

Comment: I have done:
ALTER TABLE wp_dict_text_en_temp3 DROP INDEX sent;
ALTER TABLE wp_dict_text_en_temp3 ADD FULLTEXT(sent);

After that, the compression was gone.
I ran myisampack and myisamchk again and the problem is the same, no stopwords can be found in the query.

Comment: *I ran myisampack and myisamchk again* myisampack compresses. myisamchk may uncompress. Are you sure that the compression was gone after and not before FTI recreation?

Comment: Yes, I did it again. After I drop and re-create FTI, the compression disappeared (the table increased in size and is available for editing).

Comment: Interestingly, one myisampack command reduced the table by 15%, while the myisampack + myisamchk command reduced it by 52%.

Comment: MyISAM dose not index any "word" that shows up in more than half the rows; could this explain the problem?

Comment: The table contains an ID and one field with different sentences. All sentences are unique, so it is impossible for these words to be in more than half of the rows.